# vlang: error: Option function field must be unwrapped first

Tags: vlang

I'm using the PICOEV lib and got this error: Option function field must be unwrapped first

```
unsafe { target.cb(event.data.fd, read_events, &pv) }
```

```
// target is defines as:
pub struct Target {
pub mut:
    fd      int
    loop_id int = -1
    events  u32
    cb      fn (int, int, voidptr) or { none}
    backend int
}
```

I can't get my head around how to implement an 'or { nill }' for unwrapping

Any help appreciated

> Got to the problem by: try to compile my own code and/ then got same error with the official PICO demo example.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just checked, it has been updated. https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/7ca23f6316ea4ee9e70ad8acb95ba5f11e34434f/vlib/picoev/picoev.v#L26C49-L26C49

If you are trying to give a default value to a function-type field the use `unsafe { nil }`.
So the struct definition would be

```
pub struct Target {
pub mut:
    fd      int
    loop_id int = -1
    events  u32
    cb      fn (int, int, voidptr) = unsafe { nil }
    backend int
}
```

When using `cb` field, we need to check if it is not nil

```
if target.cb != unsafe { nil } {
    target.cb(event.data.fd, read_events, &pv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is the `Option` type. The use of `unsafe { nil }` is typically discouraged now that `Option` type is available as `struct` fields. You can view the [Options/Results](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#optionresult-types-and-error-handling) section of the docs for more info. Notice the `?` before the type of the `cb` field:

```
pub struct Target {
pub mut:
    fd      int
    loop_id int = -1
    events  u32
    // this field is assigned the `none` keyword by default
    cb      ?fn (int, int, voidptr)
    backend int
}
```

Then to access the `Option` field try this:

```
if cb := target.cb {
    cb(event.data.fd, read_events, &pv)
}
```